# Verify file is copied in Java

Tags: java, copy, filestream, verification

I'm working on moving some files to a different directory in my project and it's working great, except for the fact that I can't verify it's moved properly.

I want to verify the length of the copy is the same as the original and then I want to delete the original. I'm closing both FileStreams before I do my verification but it still fails because the sizes are different. Below is my code for closing the streams, verification and deletion.

```
 in.close();
 out.close();

 if (encCopyFile.exists() && encCopyFile.length() == encryptedFile.length())
     encryptedFile.delete();
```

The rest of the code before this is using a Util to copy the streams, and it's all working fine so really I just need a better verification method.

Comment: Why would you expect that a write operation that did not throw an exception somehow produced an unidentical file to its source?

Comment: Because crazier things have happened, and while data loss wouldn't be the end of the world I'd rather it not happen on my watch.

Comment: how are you reading/writing the file?  and is this a binary or text file?

Comment: I'm using FileInputStream to open the original and then using the Util in the jfree library to copy the stream to a FileOutputStream. However, I think the verification might not be the problem because trying a different method showed that the .delete() method for one of my files isn't working. Why only 1 file... I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could include a checksum in your copy operation. Perform a checksum on the destination file and see that it matches a checksum on the source.

Comment: I think you're initial comment was right on with me being paranoid, I was looking at the wrong problem and you were the first to call me out on it, so you get the answer. I may have to open a new thread to figure out why my delete isn't working though.

Answer (score 4):

One wonderful way you can check is to compare md5 hashes. Checking file length doesn't mean they are the same. While md5 hashes doesn't mean they are the same either, it is better than checking the length albeit a longer process.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Are identical: " + isIdentical("c:\\myfile.txt", "c:\\myfile2.txt"));
    }

    public static boolean isIdentical(String leftFile, String rightFile) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        return md5(leftFile).equals(md5(rightFile));
    }

    private static String md5(String file) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        File f = new File(file);
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int read = 0;
        try {
            while ((read = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                digest.update(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            byte[] md5sum = digest.digest();
            BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, md5sum);
            String output = bigInt.toString(16);
            return output;
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, md5sum); String output = bigInt.toString(16);` is an interesting way to generate hex string for digest.

Comment: +1 for giving me a more accurate method with an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could use commons io:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.contentEquals(File file1, File file2)
```

or you could use checksum methods:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils:
static Checksum checksum(File file, Checksum checksum) //Computes the checksum of a file using the specified checksum object.
static long checksumCRC32(File file) //Computes the checksum of a file using the CRC32 checksum routine.
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that lib available on my project so that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If you get no exception while copying streams, you should be OK. Make sure you don't ignore exceptions thrown by close method!

**Update:** If you use `FileOutputStream`, you can also make sure everything was written properly by calling `fileOutputStream.getFD().sync()` before closing your `fileOutputStream`.

Of course, if you want to absolutely make sure that files are the same, you can compare their checksums/digests, but that sounds bit paranoid to me.

Comment: Understanding how to use checksum is indeed useful, but I'm still stuck on this. Without an exception, I think it's incredibly unlikely that a copy operation will have bad results. Even over a network I would expect the interfaces to those protocols to handle this sort of thing for the developer.

Comment: @yock: yes, I have actually seen FileOutputStream.close() method throwing IOException when writing file over NFS.

Answer (score 1):

If the sizes are different, perhaps you are not flushing the output stream before closing it.

Which file is bigger? What are the sizes of each file? Have you actually looked at the two files to see what is different?